# System.DirectoryServices - The server is not operational

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, windows-authentication, directoryservices

I get an error by a website, on which I use Windows Authentication.

Strange things:

- Only occurs if user is not yet saved into database (new unknown user)
- Appears only on live system, everything fine on local development environment

This is what I get in a logging mail:

> Source : System.DirectoryServices
>
> Message: The server is not operational.
>
> Trace:
>   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
>   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
>   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject()
>   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindAll(Boolean findMoreThanOne)
>   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindOne()
>   at Smarthouse.Labs.DataAccess.UserListManager.SaveUser(String windowsUserName)

This is how I implement DirectorySearch:

```
private void SaveUser(string windowsUserName)
{
    string[] domainAndUser = windowsUserName.Split('\\');
    string domain = domainAndUser[0];
    string username = domainAndUser[1];

    DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain);
    DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);

    try
    {
        // Bind to the native AdsObject to force authentication.
        search.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + username + ")";
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sn");
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("givenName");
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");

        SearchResult result = search.FindOne();

        if (result == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("No results found in Windows authentication.");
        }

        User userToSave = new User();
        userToSave.FirstName = (String) result.Properties["givenName"][0];
        userToSave.LastName = (String) result.Properties["sn"][0];
        userToSave.Email = (String) result.Properties["mail"][0];
        userToSave.Username = windowsUserName;
        userToSave.Guid = Guid.NewGuid();

        SaveUser(userToSave);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Error authenticating user. " + ex.Message, ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        //Dispose service and search to prevent leek in memory
        entry.Dispose();
        search.Dispose();
    }
}
```

If more code examples are needed just tell me.

Comment: windowsUserName = MyDomainName\\taikahar

Comment: domain = MyDomainName  (fyi: it is a local intranet i am working with)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using a "plain" domain name to bind - this won't work in LDAP. Actually, if you try to bind to `LDAP://MyDomain`, what you're **really** doing is trying to bind to the **server** called `MyDomain`.

You need a valid LDAP bind string - something like `LDAP://dc=yourdomain,dc=local` or something.

To find out what your default LDAP binding context is, use this code snippet:

```
DirectoryEntry deRoot = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://RootDSE");

if (deRoot != null)
{
   string defaultNamingContext = deRoot.Properties["defaultNamingContext"].Value.ToString();
}
```

Once you have that string - use that as your bind string to your LDAP server.

And if you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context -- no domain name needed, uses default domain 
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// find a user
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, username);

if(user != null)
{
   // do something here....     
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!

Comment: I'll have a look on that on monday. Thank you a lot:) Had to fix other stuff on live websites and this is on low prio.

Comment: Sorry, that i hadn't time to answer for a while. I tested this one local(right domain) and everything seems to be fine. Hopefully it will also run on live system.

Comment: Finally i thought about it and changed to System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement. Easy to use and hopefulyl fixes the bug.

Comment: Part 1 worked, I don't quite get why though, (bindings? Ad has them?) I'm moving a borderline legacy app to a new domain, the old ldap string was LDAP://[fqdn]/OU=...DC=... , the new one is LDAP://OU=...,DC=... I'm so confused :)  At least it worked, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To add to [marc_s's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931332/system-directoryservices-the-server-is-not-operational/7931539#7931539), I needed to search multiple domains. 
So for each Domain I did the following:

```
DirectoryEntry deRoot = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" +"DomainName"+ "/RootDSE");
string defaultNamingContext = "LDAP://" + deRoot.Properties["defaultNamingContext"].Value.ToString();
DirectoryEntry mySearchRoot = new DirectoryEntry(defaultNamingContext);
DirectorySearcher myDirectorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(mySearchRoot);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use bind strings in the format LDAP://mydomain.com:389. I kept getting "Access is Denied" when trying to use the format LDAP://DC=mydomain,DC=com. Once I switched to the LDAP://mydomain.com:389 format, and bound using the AuthenticationTypes.ServerBind flag when constructing my DirectoryEntry, it worked great. This was in Azure App Service.

Answer (score 0):

Similar Error Happened to me (though it happened all the time and not in specific cases like pointed out here) because of a wrong Active Directory connection string. i used the corp instead the prod one .
Use something that works for another app in your organization if exists.