# How to connect and test connection to an Active Directory Server on a different computer

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, active-directory

I was given a computer in which a virtual machine is running and has an Active Directory Server. I'm connected from my computer to this one through a switch.

I've read some guides such as:https://serverfault.com/questions/130543/how-can-i-figure-out-my-ldap-connection-string and http://www.schiffhauer.com/mvc-5-and-active-directory-authentication/

But this one assumes the server is on my computer which is not. How would I build a connection string for this situation and how would I test if the connection is working?

I'm currently building an ASP.NET Web API 2 which I chose at the beguinning to have no authentication and now I need to use Active Directory for authentication on login and authorization when accessing certain pages.

PS: I had never even heard of Active Directory until this was asked of me so sorry if this is a really simple question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connection string to connect to Active Directory using LDAP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15157746/connection-string-to-connect-to-active-directory-using-ldap)

Comment: AD will not help you with having absolutely no authentication in your ASP.net project. You still have to get the user information from the client machine to the server. As the server it the one who is actually executing the code. A step by step 'tutorial' about how to do that can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650307.aspx . for your connection string you simply enter your domain name. (same as what you use to include a client machine into your domain)